# How to make sure every div of a class has the same amount of a specific element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

ok,maybe its my noobness,but i cant wrap my head around this particular problem

In this test we have a button with id `#add-div` which purpose is to append the same div with class `.container` to body on every click.

We also have another button with id `#add-boxes` which purpose is to append a red box with class `.redbox` to every div with the `.container` class.

the `.container` div has a button inside which does the same thing as the `#add-boxes` button.

Lets say we have a scenario where we throw a couple of divs there,and we also fill them with 2 boxes each like this :

[image]

and then we add another div which is empty like this :

[image]

what is the logic i should follow to make sure the new div will appear with the same amount of red boxes inside it as the previous ones like this : ?

[image]

snippet to visualize my concept :

```js
$(document).on('click', '#add-div', function () {
$("body").append("<div class=containers><button>ADD BOXES</button></div>")
});

function redBoxObj(){
var box = document.createElement("div");
box.className = "redbox"

return box
}




$(document).on('click', '.containers button,#add-boxes', function () {

$(".containers").each(function(){
    $(this).append(redBoxObj())
  });

});
```

```css
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin:2px;
}
button{
position:relative;
float:left;
clear:both;
}
.containers{
position:relative;
float:left;
padding:3px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color:lightcyan;
clear:both;
}

.redbox{
position:relative;
float:left;
border:none;
width:30px;
height:30px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="add-boxes">ADD BOXES</button><button id="add-div">ADD DIV</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is cloning the existing "container div" when there is one, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-div', function() {
  if ($('.containers').length) {
    $("body").append($('.containers').first().clone());
  } else {
    $("body").append("<div class=containers><button>ADD BOXES</button></div>")
  }

});
```

I created a fiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/adamcai/y3ekjzLs/2/